# How to draw a flickering circle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geometry, drawing

I have no idea how to draw this circle. Please give me a direction that how to proceed this question. Thank everyone for helping me.

I try to draw a flickering circle by using blink(), but it was nothing happened. And i find that the blink() function is no longer work.

Comment: [String.prototype.blink()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/blink) is deprecated

Comment: Yes, i just know it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50">
  <animate
      attributeName="fill"
      values="black;white;black"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try again by this code.